# Why use literals over arrays in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, literals

Other than syntactic sugar, what usages are there of using the literal expressions (such as `%w`) over standard array syntax in Ruby?

Comment: If by *"standard array syntax"* you mean `[]` - it's syntax sugar too (short for `Array.new`). You can use `%w()` so that you won't have to quote a lot of strings. Other than that, there is no difference. Conciseness is a virtue on its own.

Comment: I guess I should've specified! My bad. I just wasn't aware if there was something under the hood that was different between the two shorthands.

Comment: If you don't feel it more comfortable than `[]`, then you should not use it.

Comment: @ndn: Neither of those are syntax sugar for `Array.new`. Try overriding `Array::new` and see what happens. Hint: nothing.

Comment: So they aren't direct aliases for Array.new but they should have the same effect, instantiating an array object. [] and the literal syntax are just reserved by the language separately then?

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you are correct, they are not direct synonyms as `Array.new` can take slightly different arguments and there is probably some micro optimizations done in the implementation. My point still remains.